# How to deploy third-party jar files in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, portal

I am using some third-party jar files in my liferay portal. These jar files will be used from multiple portlets in my portal.

I know that I can put my jar file inside my-portlet/WEB-INF/lib. But the problem here is it will accessible only inside that portlet. I want the jar file to be available to all portlets in my portal. How can i do this? Is there any global library where i can deploy my jar file and it can be accessed from anywhere?

Also, how to deploy this third-party jar file to production instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by two ways (for Tomcat distribution):

1. Manualy copy your *.jar to tomcat/lib/ext directory and restart Liferay
2. Write Liferay extension and put *.jar files to docroot/WEB-INF/ext-lib/global and deploy it before Liferay start. It's more preferable way that independent from Web server.

Vim

Comment: How can this jar then be deployed to production? i cant restart my production instance. Is there any other way work-around?

Comment: Are you hot deploying portlets to your production instance then?

Comment: rao_555: See [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Deploying%20an%20EXT%20WAR%20file) for Liferay <= 5.2.3 and [this](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/ext-plugins) for newer versions

Comment: Do I have to restart Liferay when I use method No. 2?

Comment: Yes. You should restart Liferay after refresh global libraries in extensions